# When doing E&M problems, I find the extreme exponents annoying. Could redefining the coulomb change this?

Tags: soft-question

When typing into my calculator things like $9\space 10^9$ or $8.85419\space 10^{-12}$ its rather annoying to write in all those exponents (yeah I know it sounds dumb), but its much nicer to do mechanics problems because you might have to type in things like $9.8$ or $2\pi \sqrt{2}$, no horrible exponents. (I know, working with Universal Gravity is frustrating but it doesn't appear too often...)

Is there any way to redefine the Coulomb so that many of the awkwardly extreme exponents can be avoided, so that everyday values could have more 'familiar' magnitudes?

Comment: There are several different systems of units that you could use, but ... you shouldn't be using numbers enough to worry that some of them are big or small. Seriously, all the important theoretical stuff happens in the manipulation and interpretation of the math, and experimenters have to deal with huge variations of parameters from situation to situation that won't go away no matter how you define your units.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm in university physics where we have homework that is numerical and sometimes in variables which wouldn't change at all, but the majority of the homework is numerical and it would be oh so nice for me not to have to type in those pesky exponents

Comment: Gaussian units (google it), have in effect set Coulomb's constant to 1.0 (dimensionless), but it jumbles up a lot of the equations relative their expression in SI units and your instructor will not be amused. Or maybe (s)he will be. Some people much prefer them.

Comment: If you have a good physics instructor, then he or she should have told you that you need to develop an intuition about the order of magnitude of things. What's the charge of an electron? What's an eV in J? What's the size of a hydrogen atom? Avogadro's number? Seconds in a day? How strong is gravity compared to the electric force? If you know these things you can answer many physics questions, especially of the go/no-go type with simple back of the envelope approximations.

Comment: [You're using the wrong book](http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/~siegel/history.html)